# Unable to browse the ubuntu Azure instance (VM) using its firewall public IP in the browser

Tags: azure, nginx, firewall, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

**Firstly**, I have created the Virtual Network with the following configuration:

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Region | Central India |
| Azure Bastion | Enabled |
| Azure Firewall | Enabled |
| Tier | Basic |

Created the New Basic Policy & Azure Firewall Public IP address in the same section and then created.

**Secondly**, Virtual machine of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with **`No Public IP`** in the same location and same Virtual Network.

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Availability Options | Availability Zones |
| Availability Zone | Zones 1 |
| Size | Standard_B2s - 2 vcpus, 4GB Memory |
| Authentication type | SSH public key |
| public IP | None |

**Third Step**: Firewall Manager > Azure Firewall Policies > DNAT Rules > Added a Rule Collection with the following options:

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | firewall-nginx-rulecln |
| Rule Collection Type | DNAT |
| Priority | 100 |
| Rule Collection group | DefaultDnatRuleCollectionGroup |
| Rules | No Rules |

In the Same Page of Firewall Policy, DNAT Rules Section > Click on "Add rule":

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Rule Collection Group | DefaultDnatRuleCollectionGroup |
| Rule Collection | Selected the previously created group |
| Name | firewall-rule |
| Source Type | IP Address |
| Source IP Addresses | MySystemsIPgotfrom https://whatismyipaddress.com/ |
| Destination IP Addresses | Public IP of Firewall |
| Protocol | TCP |
| Destination Ports | 4000 |
| Translated Type | IP Address |
| Translated FQDN | VM's Private IP |
| Translated Port | 80 |

**Firewall Rule**:

[image]

**Fourth Step**:
Connected to the Ubuntu VM through Bastion Host and did the following steps present in this [GitHub Page](https://github.com/iam-veeramalla/Azure-zero-to-hero/blob/main/Day-07/01-nginx-install.md).

**Problem**:

Able to get the content present in index.html by sending the command `curl localhost:80`:

```
azureuser@linuxvm02:~$ curl localhost:80
<h1>I have learnt Azure Networking Concept, today</h1>
```

but not able to get the result in the browser if I enter the `Firewall-PublicIP:Port` (For eg, `4.247.159.154:4000`)

[image]

Comment: Kindly check the network security group  associated with the subnet where your Ubuntu VM is deployed. Make sure that the NSG allows inbound traffic on port 4000 from the public IP address of your machine.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4m5nuzK.png - VM is deployed to default Subnet where No NSG is associated and https://i.imgur.com/zy2xjMA.png - these are the available rules in NSG.

Comment: Based on the screenshots, it appears that you have added the VNet for both the source and destination in the NSG rules for outbound traffic. However, you are accessing a public IP from the VM, which is not within the VNet range and also attach NSG to the subnet.

Comment: I'm accessing the Firewall's Public IP not the VM's Public IP. You can watch the tutorial at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJSRYQQEUQc) which I followed.

Comment: Im able to access the application using firewall public IP 
[Here](https://i.imgur.com/nlo5Rgm.png)

Comment: Please review the Firewall Policy and rules that you have configured

Comment: Can you see my firewall policy rules what I configured - in the Question description itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256785/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-vamsi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to browse the ubuntu Azure instance (VM) using its firewall public IP in the browser.

If you are unable to access the application using the Fi`rewall Public IP`, make sure to check the **Azure Firewall Rules** and **Security Group Rules**. Additionally, try accessing the application from another network, as there is a chance that traffic may be blocked, especially if you are using a corporate network.

Here are the steps to create an application on a `Linux VM` with a **firewall public IP**.

1. Create a `Virtual Network` with azure bastion and azure firewall.

> Make sure to select Azure Bastion and Azure Firewall, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

**Vnet Subnet configuration**

[image]

2. Once the **VNet** is complete, create a virtual machine

[image]

**VM network configuration**

[image]

Make sure to download the **private key** to your local machine, as it is required to connect to the **VM**.

[image]

3. Once create the VM, `Go to Firewall Manager > Azure Firewalls > Select your firewall and open > Firewall policy`.

[image]

4. Open **Firewall policy > DNAT rules > Create a collection rule.**

[image]

Once the collection rule is created, add a rule by clicking **"add rule"**.

[image]

5. Connect the `VM` using bastion.

[image]

6. After connecting to the **VM**, navigate to the root folder using the command below.

```bash
    sudo su
```

7. Update the current repository

```bash
    apt-get update
```

8. Install nginx

```bash
apt-get install nginx
```

9. Navigate to **hmtl** folder using below command.

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

10. Create sample **index.html**.

```
vim index.html
```

[image]

11. I'm able to access the application using `Firewall Public IP`.

[image]

12. When I try to access the same application from corporate network, I too got the same result.

[image]

Comment: But I also given my mobile IP address which is connected to mobile data network that doesn't have any blockings. From the mobile also, unable to browse the firewall IP.

Comment: Hello VenkatV, I know the steps and I understood that the firewall public ip cannot be accessed from the corporate machine. I'm asking about mobile network and mobile ip and mobile device accessing firewall's ip.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, please share the Firewall rule configuration to understand the issue clearly.

Comment: I'm telling many times that i given firewall rules in the question description. Please check

Comment: In the question, you provided a basic description rather than the actual configuration. Could you please share the rule configuration from the portal?

Comment: The last IP you're accessing is not the same which you got in the step 11 result. The IP starts with 172 is your firewall's IP.

Comment: HI VenkatV, did you check - provided the actual firewall policy rule screenshot in the question description.

Comment: The policy you have configured its correct, Kindly restart the Nginx service and also check the VM is up and running.

Comment: HI VenkatV, please check my comment - The last IP you're accessing is not the same which you got in the step 11 result. The IP starts with 172 is your firewall's IP.  - seems to be wrong output you have given.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, Please check the my updated answer,now both 11 and 12 steps IPs are same. when I try to access the same ip from corporate network,it's blocking.

Comment: Earlier, I mistakenly added another screenshot, as there are no changes in the configuration.

Comment: If it is working in step 11, are you connected with any other network and disabled VPN?

Comment: Yes, when I try to access the same IP from corporate network, it's blocking.